# Get data from observale array

Tags: typescript

I have a question because I don't have idea for resolve this problem. I created service class :

```
export class FamilyService {

  private baseUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/api';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getFamilyByPeselChild(pesel: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}` + `/getFamilyByPeselChild/${pesel}`);
  }
```

I will get response from server and I make a table with Family object. I want to make that when I click on row I will get id of this object. Family class structure:

```
import {Father} from './Father';
import {Child} from './Child';

export class Family {
  public id: number;
  public father: Father = new Father();
  public childList: Array<Child> = new Array<Child>();
}
```

The question is how can I get this id from observable array? Thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subscribe to the observable like this:

```
getFamilyByPeselChild.subscribe((response) => {
    this.id = response.id   // assuming your response is an object
});
```

I'm not very clear if this is what you are expecting...If not then please provide more detail.